# Show selected value in material select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this [code](https://angular-material-select2.stackblitz.io) and I am wondering how can I be able to show the selected value on the label. Thank you!

Comment: Paste your code here..

Comment: Have you tried `[selected]`

Comment: @A.Sakkeer `on the label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #select [placeholder]="selectedLanguage?.value?.value || 'Language'" (selectionChange)="selectedLanguage = $event"
     panelClass="panelResponsive">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let language of filteredLanguages" [value]="language">
            <span>{{language.value}}
            </span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```